# mongodb aggregation matching properties

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a user_status collection and its schema is like this

```
const userStatus = mongoose.model(
  'user_status',
  new mongoose.Schema(
    {
      user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'user'
      },
      isActive: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  )
);
```

I need to get all the active users count for a given specific month (1, 2, etc..)

I tried this. But this snippet is not giving expected output

```
// get all active user count for a specific month
router.post('/report', async (req, res) => {
  const selectedMonth = req.body.month;

  console.log('month', selectedMonth);

  const usersStatus = await UserStatus.aggregate([
    { $project: { month: { $month: '$updatedAt' } } },
    {
      $match: { $and: [{ month: { $eq: selectedMonth } }, { isActive: true }] }
    },
    { $group: { _id: '$user', count: { $sum: 1 } } }
  ]).exec();
  res.status(200).send(usersStatus);
});
```

Could you please tell me where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have vanished the `isActive` and `user` field  after the first [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage

You can use below aggregation

```
const usersStatus = await UserStatus.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": { "month": { "$month": "$updatedAt" } } },
  { "$match": { "month": selectedMonth, "isActive": true }},
  { "$group": { "_id": "$user", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } }
])
```

Or even more convenient way using [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)

```
const usersStatus = await UserStatus.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "$expr": {
      "$and": [
        { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$updatedAt" }, selectedMonth] },
        { "$eq": ["$isActive", true] }
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$group": { "_id": "$user", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } }
])
```

Comment: Yes. It's working :). . I need to learn more about aggregations. Thanks for the help @Anthony